# Create many objects from an array of emails in a text area Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, invite

I am making an app where you can invite participants to a project.  I'd like to be able to invite many at once, just like when one types a bunch of email addresses into an email To: field.  When Invite form is submitted, then new objects in my :participant table will be created for each corresponding email, with a status_column marked "invited".

I am new and, though I've done an 'update.all' in a form before, I've never 'created' many from one text area.

Comment: You could ask the user to use a comma to separate each email address, or a simple space (like gmail). Then, you can just split on the string containing all the emails: `params[:project][:participants_addresses].split(/\s|,/)` (this split on both `,` (commas) and ` ` (spaces))

Comment: Thank you! But...where would I put the split?  in the Create action on the ParticipantsController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split on every comma and/or every whitespace:

```
def create
  params[:project][:participants_addresses] = params[:project][:participants_addresses].split(/\s|,/) if params[:project].try(:[], :participants_addresses).present?

  # from now params[:project][:participants_addresses] is an array of Strings
  # you can loop on each email address and create Participant records in the DB,
  # having the status as "invited"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an input in the form like that:

`<%= f.text_field :emails_list %>`

where you ask for emails separated by commas.

Then in the controller you can do something like that:

```
emails = params[:your_object][:emails_list]
emails_list = emails.split ","

emails_list.each do |email| #iterate on email addresses
end
```